# Better way to listen for click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a graph that is controlled by two calendars. If the user clicks and opens the one calendar to select a date then clicks anywhere off of the calendar that calendar should close. Since there is a "start date" and an "end date" calendar they are both closing each other. So I am attempting to come up with a new solution. My current solution looks something like this.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if (this !== $("#startDate") && this !== #("#endDate")) {
        $("#startDate").hide();
        $("#endDate").hide();
    }
});
```

Obviously, this if statement fires on *every* click. I think this is a poor way of doing this but cannot think of a smarter way. Anyone have a better way? Remember, there are two calendar's that can't close each other.

Comment: If you are using firebug, you can right click and inspect element to get a better selector than just $(document)

Comment: Is it possible to have both open at the same time? If so, are you asking "when you click outside of both of them, how can I tell which one you wanted to close?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id !== "startDate" && e.target.id !== "endDate") {
        $("#startDate").hide();
        $("#endDate").hide();
    }
});
```

There is a better way to implement this. You can stop the event propagation on the elements where you don't want the calender to close. So in your case it is calendar opener links.

Try this

```
$("#startDate, #endDate").click(function(e){

   e.stopPropagation();

});
```

Now you dont have to check any condition while hiding the start and end date.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   $("#startDate").hide();
   $("#endDate").hide();
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't think of. I had to stopPropagation on a project over a year ago and just couldn't think of what the hell I did.

Answer (score 1):

Handling *every* click really isn't all that bad. Still you could optimize the code in the click event handler slightly:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    if (id !== "startDate" && id !== "endDate") {
        $("#startDate").hide();
        $("#endDate").hide();
    }
});
```

That saves you from constructing jQuery wrappers for #startDate and #endDate on every single click, just to do a comparison.

By the way, if you *already* have click event handlers for #startDate and/or #endDate and if you are calling e.stopPropagation() in or returning false from that/those click event handlers, you do not need to do the check in the `$(document).click` handler. If you stop propagation of the click event after you have handled it, it won't get to the document level. For example, assuming you are handling clicks on both:

```
$("#startDate").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Handle startDate click logic...
});

$("#endDate").click(function(e) {
    // Handle endDate click logic...
    return false;
});

$(document).click(function() {
    // Clicked element cannot be #startDate or #endDate.
    $("#startDate").hide();
    $("#endDate").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a class to both calendars to check against.  This way also, if you need to make other objects clickable without closing for any reason you can apply that class to them as well.  Also, using .is() will make the code a bit cleaner.

http://api.jquery.com/is/

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('.calendar')) {
        $("#startDate").hide();
        $("#endDate").hide();
    }
});
```

You could also use a second class to tell what you want to close.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('.calendar')) {
        $(".calendarClose").hide();
    }
});

<div id="startDate" class="calendar calendarClose"></div>
<div id="endDate" class="calendar calendarClose"></div>
```

Comment: `this` refers to the `document` object in this case and not the clicked element (and you would need to wrap it in `$()` to call jQuery functions on it). Also there is the jQuery function `.hasClass()` which seems like it would work great here.

Comment: True, used to having click on a specific object.

Comment: @Jasper Yes, the .hasClass() can work, but if there is ever a need to change the relevant selectors. Maybe they don't want the calendar to close when any <input> tags are clicked, they can just modify the selector in the .is() call.